# Apache Geode where is region attribute defined?

Tags: geode

I am new to apache geode.For example,I want to do a query like in Document:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT * FROM /exampleRegion p WHERE p.status = 'active'
> ```

But it really puzzles me that where does attribute (or maybe called column/key?) `status` come from. Take relational database for example,I can define schemas for a particular table using `create table`,but the example here is not clear to me.

Cound anyone please explain where the `status` is defined or generated? Please show an instance to me how to put a record into `exampleRegion` with some data together with attribute `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Geode is an in-memory data grind, not a traditional RDBMS system.
Each region contains Java Objects, so there's no `schema` notion nor anything like that (well, there is if you fix the `key-class` or the `value-class` before hand).

In the example you attached, there's probably a Java Object inserted into the region which has a `status` field or attribute of type `java.lang.String`, that's where the `status` comes from.

Please have a look at the [Geode Querying Example](https://github.com/apache/geode-examples/tree/develop/queries), it contains a full example of how to insert data into a region (the "schema" here would be the `EmployeeData.java` class) and how to query the region using OQL.